# Building a substrate node template with a global cargo `target` directory

Tags: substrate-node-template, wasm, build, cargo

I'm trying to build a `substrate-node-template` with the following command:

```sh
cargo build
```

I have my cargo `target-dir` set inside a global `~/.cargo/config.toml` file:

```
[build]
target-dir = "/home/foo/.cargo/target"
```

The environment variable `CARGO_TARGET_DIR` is unset.

Normally this configuration builds everything inside the `~/.cargo/target` directory - which saves a lot of space on disk (not having to duplicate build artifacts for every project).

Note that this also works for Wasm projects, which usually end up in the `.cargo/target/wasm32-unknown-unknown` directory.

That said, it seems that the `build.rs` script uses a `wasm_builder` crate, which does something unusual - it creates a new Wasm project inside of the `target` directory (under `wbuild`) and builds that project separately, causing the build to fail since it does not respect the global `target-dir` setting and also ignores the `CARGO_TARGET_DIR` variable so it can't find the correct build artifacts.

The cargo build hangs forever at the `node-template-runtime` step, most likely due to a deadlock, i.e. the parent `cargo build` is using the global `~/.cargo/target/` directory and the secondary runtime build is also using the global `~/.cargo/target/` directory instead of the nested `./target/debug/wbuild/node-template-runtime` as it expects:

```
Building [=======================> ] 839/843: node-template-runtime(build)
```

If I export the `CARGO_TARGET_DIR=target` env var the build proceeds further but then fails at the `build.rs` step for `node-template-runtime` because the `build.rs` script ignores the `CARGO_TARGET_DIR`:

```
Compiling node-template-runtime-wasm v1.0.0 (/home/foo/substrate/substrate-node-template/target/debug/wbuild/node-template-runtime)
Finished release [optimized] target(s) in 52.13s
  thread 'main' panicked at 'Failed to compact generated WASM binary.: Error(HeapOther("Can't read from the file: Os { code: 2, kind: NotFound, message: \"No such file or directory\" }"))', /home/foo/substrate/substrate.mod/utils/wasm-builder/src/wasm_project.rs:618:14
  stack backtrace:
     0: rust_begin_unwind
               at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/std/src/panicking.rs:498:5
     1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
               at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/core/src/panicking.rs:116:14
     2: core::result::unwrap_failed
               at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/core/src/result.rs:1690:5
     3: core::result::Result<T,E>::expect
               at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/core/src/result.rs:975:23
     4: substrate_wasm_builder::wasm_project::compact_wasm_file
               at /home/foo/substrate/substrate.mod/utils/wasm-builder/src/wasm_project.rs:617:3
     5: substrate_wasm_builder::wasm_project::create_and_compile
               at /home/foo/substrate/substrate.mod/utils/wasm-builder/src/wasm_project.rs:130:3
     6: substrate_wasm_builder::builder::build_project
               at /home/foo/substrate/substrate.mod/utils/wasm-builder/src/builder.rs:244:30
     7: substrate_wasm_builder::builder::WasmBuilder::build
               at /home/foo/substrate/substrate.mod/utils/wasm-builder/src/builder.rs:162:3
     8: build_script_build::main
               at ./build.rs:4:2
     9: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once
               at /rustc/9d1b2106e23b1abd32fce1f17267604a5102f57a/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:227:5
  note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: build failed
```

The only way I can successfully build it is if I unset the global `target-dir` option and leave cargo to use the default `./target` directory for the entire build.

It seems that most of the build problems stem from the assumptions that the `wasm_builder` crate makes, hence the `build.rs` only works if it uses the default cargo target directory location.

Based on git history [issue#7532](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/7532), the reason the `wasm_builder` ignores the `CARGO_TARGET_DIR` is because it used to cause a cargo deadlock, since the `build.rs` script would try to build inside of the same `target` directory as the parent cargo process - but this seems to cause additional issues when not using the default target dir path.

For comparison, this is the successful build directory structure under `./target`:

```
target
    debug
        wbuild
            node-template-runtime
                target
                    release
                    wasm32-unknown-unknown
                        release
                            node_template_runtime.wasm
                node_template_runtime.wasm
```

And this is the unsuccessful build directory structure:

```
target
    debug
        wbuild
            node-template-runtime
                <empty>
    release
    wasm32-unknown-unknown
        release
            target
            node_template_runtime.wasm
```

Comment: It is a somewhat unrelated question, but are you using a compiler cache like `cachepot` or `sccache` for reducing build times even further than the common target folder allows you?

Comment: Yes, I use `sccache`.

Comment: @Rtsne42 @wigy I am unfamiliar with `cachepot` and `sccache`, what are they and how do they help? Maybe I can google the first question, but please help me understand if I should start using it for faster build.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What seems to be happening is that the `wasm_builder` builds the runtime in a nested location in the target directory:

```
target
    debug
        wbuild
            node-template-runtime
                src
                Cargo.toml
                Cargo.lock
```

Which should create a nested target directory for the runtime build:

```
target
    debug
        wbuild
            node-template-runtime
                target
                src
                Cargo.toml
                Cargo.lock
```

But since the `target-dir` is set in `.cargo/config.toml` the build script puts both target directories in the global path instead:

```
.cargo/target
    debug (parent)
    release (child)
    wasm32-unknown-unknown (child)
```

Then when the `build.rs` script tries to compress the wasm binary it can't find it under the nested location and fails with the "No such file or directory" error as show above.

I'm supposing that a short-term solution would be to make the `wasm_builder` also ignore the `target-dir` setting the same way it ignores the `CARGO_TARGET_DIR` as they seem to be related problems.